# Looping through all the records and changing them in between

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

Im just a bit curious as to what would happen in this scenario

(My setup is a MongoDB, Ruby on Rails via MongoID)

```
Models.all.each do |model|
    model.destroy           #delete the record
    newmodel = model.new    #make a new record
    newmodel.someinfo = info  #fill it with some info
    newmodel.save   #save it
end
```

If we destroy the records while looping through and make a new one.
Would we loop through forever (because we're deleting the old one and adding a new one)

What I mean to ask is perhaps would we loop through the new records that we would have added (on the line that says `#save it`)

If not how would we code it to get that desired effect (loop through twice?) - Say I wanted an infinitely processing rake task?

Comment: I am.. its been running over 2 hours now.

Comment: Hence the confusion, not sure if its supposed to go forever.. what about those who run into something similar?

Comment: Try it in a dummy DB with only like 2 records in it and print a status as you delete and make each one?

Comment: #each works on array, containing documents that exist on db *before* you destroy or add any documents.

Comment: If you want an infinitely processing rake task - use daemon instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have enough memory for the task you can use `Models.all.entries.each` instead of `Models.all.each`.

The way you are currently iterating through the record uses mongodb cursors, which can or can not(I am not sure) loop infinitely.

However, `Models.all.entries` will fetch the documents from db before iterating on them, so you can be sure that you will not be iterating on newly created documents. Beware, it will hog a lot of memory if you have a lot of bulky documents.